# jQuery DFP - sizeMapping returning wrong sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-dfp

I am trying to set up a responsive panorama banner using 
[jQuery DFP - A jQuery implementation for Google DFP](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js)

When refreshing it seems to disregard the size mapping and return a random line item from DFP, regardless of screen size/line item size.

Anyone know what could be the issue here?

Check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/martink/pen/zjLrbx) for example

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.dfp({
            'dfpID': '1007180',
            enableSingleRequest: false,
            sizeMapping: {
                'studentum_se_panorama_pushdown': [
                    { browser: [1024, 768], ad_sizes: [[980, 240], [980, 120]] },
                    { browser: [980, 480], ad_sizes: [728, 90] },
                    { browser: [0, 0], ad_sizes: [320, 100] }
                ]
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="adunit" data-adunit="studentum_se_panorama_pushdown" data-dimensions="320x100,728x90,980x120,980x240"></div>
```

DFP Settings
[image: line item settings]
[image: line items]